# I am trying to get this Arrayformula to work

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum, google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to get this Arrayformula to work so I can plot this formula instead of calculating every Y myself.

```
=arrayformula(Sum(IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1;IFS(AB3:AB294>0;0;Z3:Z294>Y$1;Y3:Y294-(F3:F294*Y$1));0)-(Sum(IF(and(J3:J294>0;Z3:Z294>Y$1);F3:F294;0)))))
```

It gives me the (correct) return of this part:

```
Sum(IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1;IFS(AB3:AB294>0;0;Z3:Z294>Y$1;Y3:Y294-(F3:F294*Y$1));0)
```

But it doesn't subtract the second part:

```
-(Sum(IF(and(J3:J294>0;Z3:Z294>Y$1);F3:F294;0)))))
```

I am quite new to extensive Excel/Sheets formulas so I have no idea how to get this to work, It is also quite weird that the second part doesn't add up even seperate from the first part. So this also doesn't work:

```
=arrayformula(Sum(IF(and(J3:J294>0;Z3:Z294>Y$1);F3:F294;0)))
```

I hope it makes some sense without any context, thanks in advance!

Have a great rest of your day,

P.S. Please ignore simple mistakes, I don't code that often in Sheets ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` is not supported. instead of

```
and(J3:J294>0;Z3:Z294>Y$1)
```

do this:

```
(J3:J294>0)*(Z3:Z294>Y$1)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response! When I insert: 
`
=arrayformula(Sum(IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1;IFS(AB3:AB294>0;0;Z3:Z294>Y$1;Y3:Y294-(F3:F294*Y$1));0)-(Sum(IF(J3:J294>0)*(Z3:Z294>Y$1)))))
`
I get an error:
`
Incorrect number of arguments for IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but found 1 arguments.
`
Its probably just a small thing I am missing...

Comment: @Foenkelito should be `IF((J3:J294>0)*` not `IF(J3:J294>0)*`

Comment: It still gives the same error as before,

Comment: @Foenkelito `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1; IFS(AB3:AB294>0; 0; Z3:Z294>Y$1; Y3:Y294-(F3:F294*Y$1)); 0)-(SUM(IF((J3:J294>0)*(Z3:Z294>Y$1); F3:F294; 0)))))`

Comment: It is pretty strange, when I use that piece of code in the full formula it gives me a completely wrong value, but when I use it separate from the full code it works perfectly? Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, the second part so the code that follows after "-" is the code that represents AB which the first part uses. So when you put it in one formula it's like AB never existed? maybe that's why it works separately from each other. Could this make any sense?

Comment: @Foenkelito most likely this is caused by IFS which is not recommended to use within arrayformulas. try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1; IF(AB3:AB294>0; 0; IF(Z3:Z294>Y$1; Y3:Y294-(F3:F294*Y$1); 0))))-(SUM(IF((J3:J294>0)*(Z3:Z294>Y$1); F3:F294; 0))))`

Comment: @Foenkelito see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471